# "ionic : command not found" on Mac after install ionic Cordova

Tags: installation, ionic4

I try to install ionic 4 on my iMac.
I use this : `npm install -g ionic Cordova`

when I use ionic command I have this error : " ionic : command not found "

At the end I have this : `+ ionic@5.2.7
+ cordova@9.0.0`

and when I try to use some Cordova command it work.

Answer (score 5):

From your question, I see you have installed node, cordova, ionic already to resolve error : " ionic : command not found"
Try this out:
1. check your:

```
npm root
```

2. check:

   npm root -g

You should have something like:
"/usr/local"

4. If your result is different, then that is where your problem is coming from.

Change it using:

```
npm config set prefix /usr/local
```

5. Your can check your result with:

   npm root -g
6. You should have something like

"/usr/local/lib/node_modules"

7. You can now re-install everything with "-g"

   sudo npm install -g cordova

   sudo npm install -g ionic

If you still have the previous installation, please remember to uninstall first be re-installation with:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g cordova

sudo npm uninstall -g ionic
```

Comment: Great solution! You saved my time, thank you my friend!